# How to copy worksheet data and style with EPPlus C#?

Tags: c#, epplus

I am saving data to a new worksheet with EPPlus. But it doesn't copy the styles of the worksheet I use as a template. How can I do that?[image]

As seen in the picture, the cell height of the template is 25, while the cell height of the new worksheet I created using the template is 18. I want the cell height in the new worksheet to be 25 as well.

My code is here..

```
FileInfo template = new FileInfo(path + @"\Template\template.xlsx");
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(template))
{
 FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(fileCheck);
 using(ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
 {
  ExcelWorksheet ws0 = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
  ws0.Cells["A8"].Value = texedit2.Text;
  pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet2", ws0);
  pack.SaveAs(newFile);
 }
}
```

Is there any other solution?

Comment: One solution is to first copy the file then insert the data. Copy with Io. I think is better to use value2 not value

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to do this loop through each row in the new worksheet and manually set the height to match the corresponding row in the template.

```
ExcelWorksheet ws0 = package.Worksheets[0];
ExcelWorksheet newWorksheet = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet2", templateWorksheet);

for(int i = 0; i < ws0.Dimensions.Row + 1; i++)
{
    newWorksheet.Rows[i].CustomHeight = true;
    newWorksheet.Rows[i].Height = ws0.Rows[i].Height;
}
```